# Share method across multiple views

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have multiple that display data in tables. In some of those columns I want to perform formatting of the data.

I've achieved this by adding a the following to my views:
`@{ string FormatData(string data) { //return do some formatting } }`

Now the formatting has become the same across multiple views and I want to avoid copy pasting the same function across them. What is the best way to share this method across my views?

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways, but suspect you are fairly new to programming, so you make a static class (MyFormatter) with a static method (MyMethod) and then you use that.

```
MyFormatter.MyMethod("whatever");
```